# CMV Geocoder widget - adding a location symbol

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, configurable-map-viewer

Is there a geocoderOption to have a symbol dropped on the map for a location searched for with the CMV Geocoder widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trae,

Here's how I accomplished this for a client:

```
define([
    'esri/symbols/PictureMarkerSymbol'
], function (PictureMarkerSymbol) {
    return {
        map: true,
        mapRightClickMenu: true,
        expanded: true,
        collapsible: false,

        geocoderOptions: {
            autoComplete: true,
            zoomScale: 500,
            maxLocations: 20,
            highlightLocation: true,

            symbol: new PictureMarkerSymbol({
                angle: 15,
                xoffset: -12,
                yoffset: 24,
                type: 'esriPMS',
                url: 'http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Basic/RedFlag.png',
                contentType: 'image/png',
                width: 18,
                height: 18
            }),

            arcgisGeocoder: {
                placeholder: 'Search for an Address'
            }
        }
    };
});
```

This was done in the separate `geocoder.js` config file in a common folder shared by all applications. You'll need to merge this with your own configuration settings.